# How can I use Tomcat’s built-in web server?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat6

How can I use Tomcat’s built-in web server?

Comment: what are you trying to build?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access the tomcat server without using Apache, you need to do a couple of things:

1. Enable the regular http connector (usually listening on port 8080) in the *server.xml* configuration file. The setting should already be present, but is usually commented out. Uncomment it.
2. Restart Tomcat.
3. Point your web-browser to "http://servername:8080/"

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The question is confusing, but I'm assuming you want to serve up tomcat pages with apache, as both services are made by the apache group.

Here are two resources at apache on how to do this:

http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Connectors

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/proxy-howto.html

Here is a guide at Ubuntu forms which will help if you are using Debian or Ubuntu:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=420034&highlight=tomcat